# Anyone know how to test an entire String for a match using Java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to search a `String` for an entire match.  In other words, if `String s = "I am coding"`, and I type in that I am searching for `"am"` nothing should get returned.  I need the exact String in order to get a match.  In other words, I would have to type in`"I am coding"` exactly in order for a match to be returned.

I need the regex pattern for this, since I am using `RowFiler.regexFilter(...)`.

Comment: Why do you need to use regexp?  Use String.equals().

Comment: er, the "pattern" would simply be the entire string, with left and right anchors; `"^this is my string$"`

Comment: @bdares: he needs to use it for the method `RowFilter.regexFilter(...)` which accepts a regex to filter rows of a table..

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Yes, Jack is 100% right.  The regexFilter has added a bit of complexity.

Comment: SOLUTION:  I had to set sorter.setRowFilter(...); to null sorter.setRowFilter(null);.  Thank you all for your help. :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried this: `^I am coding$`?

Comment: +1 - this is the solution described in the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#regexFilter(java.lang.String,%20int...)

Comment: Yes, this solution works. :)  However, I am having issues using it and getting my JTable to update when I use a regex that matches a postion and not an actual character.

Answer (score 2):

The regex, if it doesn't contain characters to escape is as what you are looking for: any character maches for itself and two next characters means concatenation. So, in this case, `"\AI am coding\z"` is your answer..

Comment: Sorry, I think I should clarify.  I realize typing in the entire sting will get a return.  But at the moment, when I type in even one word of the String, I get a match for the whole thing - which is what I don't want.  So if I am searching for Ice Cream stores, and type in "Baskin", Baskin Robbins should not show up.  Thanks. :)

Comment: I did in fact try it with \A and \Z, but there were issues with it and so I am trying to find the exact regex.

Answer (score 1):

On the Regex side of things:

using the start of string anchor `^` and end of string anchor `$` at the beginning and the end of your search pattern (respectively) to ensure that the search string doesn't contain anything else (i.e. it equals the pattern you're trying to match. Regex:

```
^I am Coding$
```

Ref: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

Comment: Sorry, I just realised other people have already posted this answer while I was still composing mine.

Comment: This id working...I can only match what I want with it.  However, the table is having problems because this regex uses location and not an actual pure String match.  Though I can't say why...

Comment: How do you match a position? Could you give an example?